# Check and print occurrences of an array of string in a dataset in Python

Tags: data-analysis, data-science

I want to check if an array of strings occur in a dataset and print those rows where the string array elements occur.

```
rareTitles = {"Capt", "Col", "Countess", "Don", "Dr", "Jonkheer", "Lady", 
              "Major", "Mlle", "Mme", "Ms", "Rev", "Sir"}         
 dataset[rareTitles in (dataset['Title'])]
```

I am getting following error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think the comparison should go the other way around - you look for a `dataset['Title']`, that contains string from `rareTitles`.

You can use str attribute of a pandas DataSeries, which allows as to use string methods, like `contains`. As this method accepts also a pattern as a regular expression, you can put as an argument something like 'Capt|Col...'. To join all elements of a set you can use `str.join()` method.

So the solution would be

```
dataset[dataset['Title'].str.contains('|'.join(rareTitles))]
```

Link to documentation: [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)